# Problem with App Group ID in iOS Development

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-app-group, appgroups

I'm facing an issue with my iOS app's App Group ID setup and could use some help in simple terms. When using the App Group ID "group.com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.MoEngage" in my Apple Developer account, I noticed that Xcode shows a slightly truncated version "group.com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.MoEngag" in the capabilities section.

Could someone please guide me on whether this is a common issue? How can I ensure that the correct App Group ID is used in my project settings? I've tried typing it manually, but the last character seems to get omitted. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.[image] [image]

Comment: Likely just a UI issue but you can check you entitlements to be sure